# MS Excel, How to make the IF formula spit back the value of the cell if condition is FALSE?

Tags: excel-formula

Here is the formula I am trying to run:

```
=IF((FIND("(",A24)-1),LEFT(A24,FIND("(",A24)-1),A24)
```

I thought that the last A24 meant that the cell value would be copied if the IF condition is false, but it is not being copied. How would one make that happen? Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your formula again, you haven't got a matching number of open and close brackets. Does the formula even run?

Comment: @kaybee99 You think so because up to two of the brackets do not need be closed ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is if the formula `FIND` does not find your search term `"("` it will output the error value `#VALUE!`. To correct this please consider the following formula:

```
=IF((IFERROR(FIND("(",A24)-1,FALSE)),LEFT(A24,FIND("(",A24)-1),A24)
```

`IFERROR` function makes sure if the term is not found it will output `FALSE`. Hope this helps. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for an if statement is

```
=IF(condition, value if true, value if false)
```

You have omitted the optional `value if false` so if your condition returns `false`, the statement will return a blank value.

Your current statement will return the value of cell A24 when the condition is true.

Try:
    =IF((FIND("(",A24)-1),LEFT(A24,FIND("(",A24)-1),value_if_true,A24)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the formula you asked me to try has too many arguments.